# How to block a USB device at kernel level when it's plugged(Linux)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, usb-drive

I'm trying to block a device at kernel level. 
To be specific, When USB device (USB Mass Storage Device) is plugged in, I want to get its vendorid, productid, serial and let my user space thread decide whether the device attach/detach.

And I met a problem, How could I let the driver wait for my user space thread's processed result(if the device is authorized).

Comment: It's possible to blacklist the device completely using udev, but communicating from user space to kernel space seems to be a bad practice.

Comment: when a new usb device plugged in, and the new device's info isn't in the  udev list, But I need to get the info and decide if the usb device is able to be attached, how could I do that

Comment: Read `udev` documentation carefully. Almost everything you mentioned is available to the RULE which `udev` will use to decide how to proceed.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that. Thank you a lot